# Key pressed twice

Tags: java, javafx

I want input time to `TimePicker`, press Enter, add time to a label, and input time to this `TimePicker` again and then press Enter.

So, I want the result for example "8:30 - 9:50". But when I pressed Enter for first time, `TimePicker` closed and *i* get this "8:30 - 8:30". Counters with constructions like this don't work:

```
if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER && count == 1)
```

tempTime - Label

My method:

```
@FXML
private void inputTime(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        LocalTime time = getTimePicker().getValue();
        tempTime.setText(time + "-");
    }

    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        LocalTime time = getTimePicker().getValue();
        tempTime.setText(tempTime.getText() + time);
        getTimePicker().setVisible(false);
        tempTime.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the count == 1?

Comment: Are you using a Dialog?  If so the OK button may be considered the default button, meaning it will fire when enter is selected.  Look that button up and turn off the default on it.

Comment: its for example, i wrote "constructions like this dont work"

Comment: i use TimePicker